# Getting a 401 error when trying to logout from React frontend, but it works fine in Postman

Tags: reactjs, express, axios

I'm encountering an issue with my React frontend application when trying to implement the logout functionality. When I attempt to logout from the frontend using a logout component, I consistently receive a 401 error. However, when I perform the logout operation directly from Postman, it works perfectly fine without any errors.

Here's a bit more detail about my setup:

Backend: Node.js with Express serving as the API endpoint for user authentication and logout.
Frontend: React application using Axios for making HTTP requests.
Here's how I'm implementing the logout functionality in my React application

**Logout Component REACT**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { setLoading, clearUser } from "../../redux/userSlice";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { CiLogout } from "react-icons/ci";

const Logout = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [isLoggingOut, setIsLoggingOut] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const handleLogout = async () => {  
    try {
     await axios.post('http://localhost:3000/users/logout',{}, {
        withCredentials: true, 
      });
      dispatch(clearUser());
      navigate('/');
          
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout error:', error);
      setError('An error occurred while logging out.');
    }
  };
  

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Logout button */}
      <CiLogout onClick={handleLogout} >
        logout
      </CiLogout>
      {error && <p>Error: {error}</p>}

    
    </div>
  );
};

export default Logout;
```

**
and the logout Controller**

```
const logout = async (req, res) => {

  try {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      return res.status(401).json({ error: "Not logged in" });
    }


    try {
      const sessionId = req.sessionID;
      await pool.query("DELETE FROM sessions WHERE sid = $1", [sessionId]);
    } catch (dbErr) {
      console.error("Error deleting session from database:", dbErr);
      // Decide whether to proceed with session destruction or return an error
    }

    // Destroy the session
    await req.session.destroy();

    res.status(200).json({ message: "Logout successful" });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error during logout:", err);
    return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
  }
};
```

**Here is my Express app aswell**

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const session = require("express-session");
const pgSession = require("connect-pg-simple")(session);
const passport = require("passport");
const path = require("path");
require("dotenv").config();
const cors = require("cors");
// Import the pool module you created
const pool = require("./db");
const productsRoutes = require("./routes/productRoutes");
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/userRoutes");
const cartRoutes = require("./routes/cartRoutes");
const orderRoutes = require("./routes/orderRoutes");

const app = express();



const sess = {
  store: new pgSession({
    pool,
    tableName: "sessions",
  }),
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false, // Add this line to explicitly set resave to false
  saveUninitialized: false, // Add this line to explicitly set saveUninitialized to false
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 10 * 60 * 1000, 
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production', 
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite:'none'
  },
}

app.use(session(sess)) 
 

app.use(express.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit:'50mb', extended: true }));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());



const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:5173', // Replace with the origin of your frontend application
  methods: 'GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE',
  credentials: true, // Allow credentials
  preflightContinue: false,
  optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));


app.use("/users", usersRoutes);
app.use("/images", express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public/images")));
app.use("/products", productsRoutes);
app.use("/cart", cartRoutes);
app.use("/orders", orderRoutes);


app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  console.error(`Error in ${req.method} ${req.url}`);
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.status(500).send("Something went wrong!");
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Comment: I’d make your logout endpoint not return a 401

Comment: For the postman its seems to be holding on to  session. Try deleting the cookie in postman before retrying.